# Why is console.log(3>2>1) outputs false?

Tags: javascript, console.log

`3>2 // true
2>1 // true
3>2>1 //false`

I don't understand if I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: `3 > 2` is true. `true > 1` is false.

Comment: just add parentheses and look what result you get. `(3 > 2) > 1 `

Answer (score 8):

In JavaScript `3>2>1` will be evaluated in the following sequence:

`(3 > 2) > 1` `// same operator (>), will be evaluated from left to right`

**To** `true > 1`

**To** `1 > 1` `// coerced true to 1`

**To** `false`

Answer (score 3):

In short

`3>2` will return `true`

so

`true > 1` will automatically `false`

What will work in this case is `(3>2) && (2>1)` which will return `true`